# Ionic 4 start tabs project Lifecycle hooks broken

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, angular8

Step1:

```
ionic start stacktabs tabs --type=angular
ionic cordova platform add android
ionic cordova run android --prod
```

Everything works.

Step 2: Check current routings:

//START: app-routing.module.ts:

```
   path: '',
   loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule)
```

//END: app-routing.module.ts:

// START: tabs-routing.module.ts:

```
            const routes: Routes = [
            {
            path: 'tabs',
                component: TabsPage,
                children: [
                 {
                    path: 'tab1',
                    children: [
                  {
                    path: '',
                    loadChildren: () =>
                      import('../tab1/tab1.module').then(m => m.Tab1PageModule)
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                path: 'tab2',
                children: [
                  {
                    path: '',
                    loadChildren: () =>
                      import('../tab2/tab2.module').then(m => m.Tab2PageModule)
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                path: 'tab3',
                children: [
                  {
                    path: '',
                    loadChildren: () =>
                      import('../tab3/tab3.module').then(m => m.Tab3PageModule)
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
                pathMatch: 'full'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
            pathMatch: 'full'
          }
        ];
```

// END: tabs-routing.module.ts:

Step: 3 Add console.log for constructor, ionViewWillEnter, ionViewDidEnter inside

```
tabs.page.ts
tab1.page.ts
tab2.page.ts

Re-run and everythings works as expected with the following console.log info:

            Inside tabs.page.ts constructor()....
            Inside tab1.page.ts constructor()....
            Inside tab1.page.ts ionViewWillEnter()....
            Inside tab1.page.ts ionViewDidEnter()....
            Inside tabs.page.ts ionViewWillEnter()....
            Inside tabs.page.ts ionViewDidEnter()....

Press tab2:
            Inside tab2.page.ts constructor()....
            Inside tab2.page.ts ionViewWillEnter()....
            Inside tab2.page.ts ionViewDidEnter()....

Press tab1:

    Inside tab1.page.ts ionViewWillEnter()....
    Inside tab1.page.ts ionViewDidEnter()....
```

Add a new page: initPage

```
ionic g page initPage
```

Check app-routing.module.ts

```
    const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'init-page',
        loadChildren: () => import('./init-page/init-page.module').then( m => m.InitPagePageModule)
      }
    ];
```

Step 4:
Add ion-button in tab1.page.html which will route to initPage:

```
<ion-button expand="full" (click)="gotoInitPage()">Go to InitPage</ion-button>

gotoInitPage()
{
this.navController.navigateForward('/init-page');
}
```

initPage shown up with no issues.

Step 5:
Add ion-button in init-page.page.html which will route back to tabs page:

```
<ion-button expand="full" (click)="backToTabsPage()">Back to TabsPage</ion-button>

backToTabsPage()
{
this.navController.navigateForward('/tabs/tab1');
}
```

Note: The bottom tabs button and tab1 page shown up for the view but from the chrome debugger:

tab1 modules never fired up at all, ie Only the tabs.page.ts got executed:

Only show tabs page log

```
Inside tabs.page.ts ionViewWillEnter()....
Inside tabs.page.ts ionViewDidEnter()....
```

Tested again by adding a back button inside initPage:
The result is the same, tab1 page module not fired up.

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="primary">
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
           <ion-back-button defaultHref="/tabs/tab1"></ion-back-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title>InitPage</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

I tried with different method on routing inside initPage with no luck:

```
this.navController.navigateRoot('/tabs/tab1');
this.router.navigateByUrl('/tabs/tab1');
```

Envirnoment:

```
        Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16 
        Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.0.4
        @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.25
        @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.25
        @angular/cli                  : 8.3.25
        @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0

        Cordova:
        Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
        Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
        Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 4 other plugins)

        Utility:
        cordova-res : 0.8.1
        native-run  : 0.3.0

        System:
        Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\louie\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
        NodeJS            : v12.14.0 (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
        npm               : 6.13.4
        OS                : Windows 10
```

Please help...thanks in advance

Comment: You wrote “everything works”. So what’s your problem and question?

Comment: Sorry Alexander Trakhimenok, having problems using the stack editor

Comment: I assume the "ion" events on tab1 are not fired when your are returning from "init-page" after navigating to it from tab1. If you go to "init-page", then hit reload and then go to up are they triggered? As far as I understand when you navigate forward you are not leaving a page. To communicate changes I usually use services with Observable properties or NgRX store.

Comment: Thanks Alex, would you share with some sample codes. I didn't expect any events handling should be needed in Ionic 4 while performing a simple route back. Thanks again !

Answer (score 2):

Just for someone having the same problem. It turns out that you need to use 
this.navController.navigateRoot('/some-route') inside the tab1 page. And
inside the initPage you need to issue the same, ie this.navController.navigateRoot('/tabs/tab1'); 
Credit to this URL: https://www.joshmorony.com/using-angular-routing-with-ionic-4/

Comment: this.navController.navigateRoot() everywhere made it work! The blog is also really useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use canDeactivate guard for parent route.

[Full demo](https://github.com/MaximBelov/ionic-framework/commit/dddfca37175bf1aebb559079d0deecfad31b4ee3)

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TabsComponent,
    canDeactivate: [IonRouterOutletHooks],
   }
 }
```

```js
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import {
  CanActivate,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
  UrlTree,
  CanDeactivate,
  ActivatedRoute
} from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { IonRouterOutlet } from '@ionic/angular';
import { LIFECYCLE_WILL_LEAVE, LIFECYCLE_DID_LEAVE } from '@ionic/core';

export interface INestedPageDeactivate {
  ionRouterOutlet: IonRouterOutlet;
  // activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute;
}

@Injectable()
export class IonRouterOutletHooks implements CanActivate, CanDeactivate<any> {
  constructor(public injector: Injector) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean|UrlTree>|Promise<boolean|UrlTree>|boolean|UrlTree {
    // console.log(this);
    // console.log(route);
    // console.log(state);
    return true;
  }
  canDeactivate(
    component: INestedPageDeactivate,
    currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
    nextState: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    // console.log(component);
    // console.log(currentRoute);
    // console.log(currentState);
    // console.log(nextState);
    if (!component.ionRouterOutlet) {
      alert('IonRouterOutletHooks->component->ionRouterOutlet');
      return false;
    }
    const stackCtrl = (component.ionRouterOutlet as any).stackCtrl;
    stackCtrl.views.reverse().forEach((view) => {
      if (!view.ref.hostView.destroyed){
        view.element.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(LIFECYCLE_WILL_LEAVE, {
          bubbles: false,
          cancelable: false,
        }));
        view.element.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(LIFECYCLE_DID_LEAVE, {
          bubbles: false,
          cancelable: false,
        }));
      }
    });
    return true;
  }
}
```